# Screen size in multiplot mode of Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have 5 sub-plots, and only four of them are showing. The code snippets are as follows, since the original code is quite long; I am not able to increase the screen size to accomodate the 5th plot, and as a result, only the first four shows up:

```
set output 'test.png'
set size 1.75,1.75
set terminal png font "/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman Bold.ttf, 10" size 1000,700   
set origin 0,0
set multiplot

#1st
set size 0.5,0.5
set origin 0,0.5
...
#2nd
set size 0.5,0.5
set origin 0,0
...
#3rd
set size 0.5,0.5
set origin 0.5,0
...
#4th
set size 0.5,0.5
set origin 0.5,0.5
...
#5th, and this one is not showing up
set size 0.5,0.5
set origin 1,0.5
...
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting the origin of the fifth plot to `1, 0.5`. This lets gnuplot plot it outside of the window.
Try this arrangement:

```
set size 1, 0.2

#first plot
set origin 0, 0.8
plot ...

#second plot
set origin 0, 0.6
plot ...

#third plot
set origin 0, 0.4
plot ...

#fourth plot
set origin 0, 0.2
plot ...

#fifth plot
set origin 0, 0.0
plot ...
```

I haven't tested the above but I hope you get the idea behind it.
Maybe the documentation about [multiplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-20500043.38) is also helpful.

Comment: Thank you, it was really useful in clearing some concepts about `set size` and `set origin`. This link says that if size is chosen more than 1, some parts of the plot may not fit the canvas - http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-23300043.58